# Minimum pairs to cover all integers from 0 to n

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

I encountered this problem in a programming contest, but couldn't solve it.

Given a range 0 to n and some pairs of numbers given in following format:

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
. .
. .
am bm
```

Where: `0<=ai,bi<=n, 1<= n,m < 1,000,000`

if `ai<=bi`, then the pair `(ai,bi)` covers all the numbers between `ai` to `bi` including themselves,

else `ai>bi` then pair `(ai,bi)` covers all the numbers between `ai` to `n` and `0` to `bi`, including themselves.

The objective is to find the minimum number of pairs such that the whole range between `0` to `n` is covered.

EDIT: If it's impossible to cover whole range with all the pairs, then result is -1.

Comment: How are the pairs generated? Or are you free to define the pairs yourself (since we want to find the minimum). I probably misunderstood the question, since if I can generate my own pair then (0, n) would cover everything, no? Also, do you mean a_i to n and 0 to b_i in second condition? Since a_i>b_i.

Comment: No the pairs are given, it might also be possible that even all of them can't cover whole range 0 to n, in that case answer is -1.

Comment: Am I missing smt ? for (3,1) so it covered from 0 to 3 and 1 to n, so all are covered?

Comment: @PhamTrung Yes, you are correct, my bad, typo. I edited the problem. (3,1) doesn't cover 2.

Comment: Can a number be covered multiple times, or does the cover have to hit each number exactly once? e.g. do 0,50 and 40,100 cover the range 0 to 100?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz It can cover multiple times.

Comment: Please provide a solved example problem.

Comment: Two more ways to solve this can be found [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17527/complexity-of-interval-cover-problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the following greedy algorithm should work.

First, sort the pairs `(x, y)` by `x` (you can split `x > y` pairs into `[0, y]`, `[x, n]`). Now, pick the first, and set a pointer `current` to the first interval.

Then, move the `current` pointer to the pair with `x <= current.y` and largest `y` (largest `y` larger than current's `y`).

At the end, check that `[first_pick.x, last_pick.y]` covers your range, and if not, output -1.

Example:

```
1 3
3 7
3 4
4 9
4 10
4 8
5 9
```

Pick `1 3`. We continue scanning through the array from this position and set current to `3 7`, because that is what still intersects the first interval and has the largest `y`. So far we have picked:

```
1 3
3 7
```

Continue scanning from here, picking `4 10`, and we are done:

```
1 3
3 7
4 10
=> [1 10] covered
```

This is easy to implement in `O(n^2)`, and it's possible to implement in `O(n)` after the sort as well by keeping track of the last picked element and second-to-last picked element. Then, you can decide, for a considered pair, whether to make that pair the new last picked element, or get rid of the current last picked element and replace it with the currently considered pair.

```
# after the sort
pick first
for i = 1 to len(given pairs):
  if pairs[i].x <= picked[-1].y and pairs[i].y > picked[-1].y:
    if len(picked) > 1 and pairs[i].x <= picked[-2].y:
      picked[-1] = pairs[i]
    else:
      picked.append(pairs[i])
```

Comment: Does this cope with the ai>bi ranges?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz you can split those into 2 pairs `[0 bi], [ai, n]`, so if it works   otherwise it should also work for those.

Comment: But wouldn't your approach then consider those 2 pairs as costing 2 if we end up using both?

Comment: You need to keep track of such split pairs, as we need the number of pairs in the end!

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz Well, keeping track if any such pairs are used should be easy, because the algorithm generates the set of chosen pairs incrementally. If we picked `k` such pairs, make sure to only count them as `floor((k + 1) / 2)`.

Comment: @IVlad Could you give a pseudo code or something, because I am not able to understand how is the second part after sort is done in O(n).

Comment: @Naman just did. If you're not familiar with python syntax, `array[-x]` means `(x - 1)-th element from the right`, so if `array = [1,2,3]` then `array[-1] == 3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would have done it, it runs in O(n^2) time, I believe.

Let's use set abstractions. Map each pair to a set of integers it covers. This abstracts out the comparison between a and b. So for `n = 6`, `(1, 5) = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`, `(3, 1) = {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}`.

Then we want to cover a set of integers 0 to n. Call this G (for goal).

Using greedy method, we iterate through all sets generated from the pairs and find the one that has the most intersection elements with G. Remove these elements from G, and add 1 to our counter.

Iterate with for loop, and finish when we have no more elements left. Or return -1, when none of the sets of a particular iteration generates any more elements from the intersection.

Each time we iterate, we reduce the size of our goal set, and we pick the pair that covers most number of elements of the remaining. Hence we are guaranteed the minimum when we are done.